# Can I hide all text in a page independently from parent elements?

Tags: javascript, css

I'd like to know how to hide/show the text in a webpage with JS or CSS without hiding the containing elements.

[image]

I've looked and looked and can't find anything about how to do this. **Is it possible?**

Obviously I could go around adding spans to all text. I'm looking for a shortcut, involving the text nodes or a CSS solution.

**Edit: If not, what about a simple work-around for the same effect?** I've noticed that I can use RGBA opacity 0 to achieve the effect without adding container elements. Only problem is, it affects the borders too. `font-color:color` would be a really useful CSS feature here...

Comment: img is not displaying. It would also help to post a sample of your html

Comment: `http://i.stack.imgur.com/MxNc7.png` path for image

Comment: You can only hide elements, not text itself. So if you want to only hide part of the text, that part has to be in its own element. Which element you choose doesn't matter.

Comment: @Dalorzo: Works fine for me.

Comment: @Dalorzo re-uploaded img, should be fine now.

Comment: Opening the image link, shows this - This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
<Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message>
<BucketName>i.stack.imgur.com</BucketName>
<RequestId>67457BEFA7D4D6E0</RequestId>
<HostId>
G8KV9JGbR0950tkeKMqdC0elth0nrnDUZfp1VOAxGQ3vfT/2DrkaYE2QPOU7IKZEPLsGhlbm8nY=
</HostId>
</Error>

Comment: @Bobz79 must be a bug, can you confirm the problem persists, or is it fixed?

Comment: You can't.   Text is contained in text nodes.  Text nodes can't be hidden on their own (only elements can be hidden like that) so you have to either remove the text nodes or hide their containing elements.

Comment: Still can't see. Btw, you can make the text invisible by setting the color same as the background ;-)

Comment: You could remove all text nodes from the document, putting them into an ordered list where you kept track of the parent node for each text node.  You could then re-insert them at any time to restore the text.

Comment: @jfriend00 I see.. That's unfortunate. Is there any kind of work-around? I notice, for example, I can use RGBA color with opacity 0 to hide text in an element without using a container span. Edit: Sent this before your suggestion. That seems pretty complex. Easier than it looks?

Comment: I added an answer that shows how to remove all text nodes and then put them all back later.

Comment: Trivial CSS trick: `body.hidetext { font-size: 0px !important; }` -- then just toggle the `hidetext` class.

Comment: @Blarmonger nicee! Much MUCH simpler and probably more efficient.

Comment: I looked for a CSS method first. Never thought of font size 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the text invisible using one line of CSS:

```
body.hidetext { font-size: 0px !important; }
```

-- then just toggle the hidetext class:

```
$('body').toggleClass('hidetext');
```

(Note that a more specific `font-size: !important` elsewhere in your CSS will override that one, however, so it may not be a flawless solution.)

Comment: I'm going to edit my question to include CSS solutions as an option. While the other answers provide creative ways of solving my problem via pure JS like I asked, this method is by far the simplest and most effient.

Comment: @jt0dd: Be sure to check the browsers you're supporting. There are legacy browser issues with this approach. jfriend00's suggestion to change your page structure is well advised, even if you do it on the fly to add wrapper elements when the page loads.

Comment: @cookiemonster both of your methods work for me, but in practice, I always try and utilize the simplest approach so long as it is effective. In my situation, I'm generating lots of dynamic content during page load (during the time I want the text hidden), so a method that doesn't risk complication in that situation is valuable

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way of removing all text nodes from the document, but keeping track of exactly where they went so you can put them all back again:

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Fd7Lq/

```
// Function for walking the DOM without recursion (faster)
// and calling a callback for each node
var treeWalkFast = (function() {
    // create closure for constants
    var skipTags = {"SCRIPT": true, "IFRAME": true, "OBJECT": true, 
        "EMBED": true, "STYLE": true, "LINK": true, "META": true};
    return function(parent, fn, allNodes) {
        var node = parent.firstChild, nextNode;
        while (node && node != parent) {
            if (allNodes || node.nodeType === 1) {
                if (fn(node) === false) {
                    return(false);
                }
            }
            // if it's an element &&
            //    has children &&
            //    has a tagname && is not in the skipTags list
            //  then, we can enumerate children
            if (node.nodeType === 1 && node.firstChild && !(node.tagName && skipTags[node.tagName])) {
                node = node.firstChild;
            } else  if (node.nextSibling) {
                node = node.nextSibling;
            } else {
                // no child and no nextsibling
                // find parent that has a nextSibling
                while ((node = node.parentNode) != parent) {
                    if (node.nextSibling) {
                        node = node.nextSibling;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})();


var visible = true;
var textNodes = [];
var textNodesNext = [];
var textNodeParents = [];
document.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (visible) {
        // collect list of all text nodes and their location
        treeWalkFast(document.body, function(node) {
            if (node.nodeType == 3) {
                textNodes.push(node);
                textNodesNext.push(node.nextSibling);
                textNodeParents.push(node.parentNode);
            }
        }, true);    
        // now remove all text nodes from the document
        for (var i = 0; i < textNodes.length; i++) {
            textNodeParents[i].removeChild(textNodes[i]);
        }
    } else {
        // put all text nodes back
        for (var i = 0; i < textNodes.length; i++) {
            textNodeParents[i].insertBefore(textNodes[i], textNodesNext[i]);
        }
        // reset out data structures
        textNodes = [];
        textNodeParents = [];
        textnodesNext = [];
    }
    visible = !visible;
});
```

Comment: Reviewing this solution later, I'm wondering: Will this work if dynamic content is added to the page between removing the nodes and putting them back?

Comment: @jt0dd - what do you expect the behavior to be if dynamic content is added while all text nodes are removed?  Whether it "works" or not depends upon what you expect the behavior to be.

Comment: Well, I'm thinking every node is sort of getting indexed and put back in that order this way, so I thought there might be a mixup if the script thinks this text node needs to go in position 3, when a new element just got placed in that spot.

Comment: Node manipulation is something I haven't needed before this, so I have a limited understanding. So, I might be 100% wrong about that.

Comment: @jt0dd - the nodes are being replaced relative to other nodes that already existed (not positions like number 3).  If you put some text in a place where text was removed, the older nodes will be replaced around that newer text without disturbing it.  Since element nodes (the containers for text) are not removed from the DOM in this process, the only place this could occur is when someone adds some text into an existing element.  If whole new elements are added that will not affect anything.

Comment: @jt0dd: Don't take this approach. Removing all the nodes and marking their place is very over-engineered and quite fragile. Your intuition about elements being added to the DOM is somewhat correct but worse would be elements that are removed or moved.

Comment: @cookiemonster - I would agree that your method looks like it would be less fragile if the HTML was being messed with while the text is hidden, BUT your empty text nodes can be combined with neighbording text nodes by the browser if other text nodes are added next to them too so any manipulations of the DOM while the text is collapsed may lead to an imperfect restoration.  This just isn't something the browser really supports so both methods are "hacks" to an extent with some vulnerabilities if the DOM is going to be manipulated while text is hidden.

Comment: @jt0dd - If you expect the page DOM to get manipulated by code you don't control while text is hidden, then I suggest you find a better way to structure your page that leads to a much less fragile way of hiding text.  For example if text you want to hide can all be in their own parent element, then you can just set that element to `display: none` and the DOM remains entirely intact, but with hidden text.

Comment: The browser doesn't automatically combine text nodes, but the developer can add to the text node by doing text manipulation in the nodes, whether using `.textContent` or direct manipulation on existing nodes, or by manually combining them using `.normalize()` or other such methods. If the user intends to do text manipulation with hidden text, then yes, mine would likely give unexpected results.